How do I improve my question relating to reading COMPORT data, and string formatting?
I posted this question today, and it even got a downvote; however, I am trying to see if its something the question is missing?
Should I include the windows.h functions in the post? In my prior version histories I did not include the opening of the Serial Port, however, I included it now. Is there anything else that I should add for post? As well is there anything that seems ambiguous from my GPS sensor receiving data in the examples I provided. My overall question what is the post missing?
C++ Insert Timestamp in between CBR of 9600

"How do I improve my question relating to reading COMPORT data, and string formatting?" The first step is to choose one of those things to ask about and not the other.

What "question"? There is no question in that post.

The starting point is: make your question useful to others.  Our mission here is to build a repository of knowledge that will be useful to others.  So if you encounter some specific, narrow, concrete uncertainty/challenge that you expect many others might face, ask about that.
Don't ask us how to solve your entire task.  For instance, asking us how to convert a CSV file to your particular desired output is not helping advance the mission of this site.  We're not here to be a coding service or a help desk for coders.  It's unlikely anyone else will have exactly the same task that you describe in your question, so it's unlikely that your question or answers to it will be helpful to anyone else again in the future.
A part of that is to identify a single question.  It needs to be very focused.  "A question relating to reading COMPORT data, and string formatting?" is too broad -- you should pick one of those things to ask about.  You shouldn't show us your entire code and entire file format.  You should identify one specific aspect you are having trouble with and boil things down to just that one, minimal aspect of the problem.  Then, you need to reduce your code to a minimal, reproducible implementation.  This might require considerable thought from you to identify one narrow aspect you are struggling with, to craft a clear problem statement, articulate your requirements clearly, identify why obvious approaches are not suitable, and to research it carefully to see whether it has been solved before.  We expect you to do that work before posting your question -- not leave it up to readers to infer.

This is a good answer. I do want to add for clarity that it is not necessary to include the contents of Windows.h (or any other system/library header) in order to create a minimal, reproducible example. Noting clearly that the functions you're calling (which, in Windows, often have generic-sounding names, like CreateFile, which someone not using Windows.h may well have written themselves) are part of the Win32 API is more than sufficient. Sometimes, people go overboard and misunderstand the MCVE expectations. The question in question is not missing anything; it needs to be reduced.
